# Spring Security 5.2.1 + spring-security-oauth2 + WebClient: how to use password grant-type

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webclient

Here is my current setup:

I'm exposing a WebClient bean with oauth2 filter:

```
@Configuration
class OAuthConfiguration {
    @Bean("authProvider")
    fun webClient(
        clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository,
        authorizedClientRepository: OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository,
        clientHttpConnector: ClientHttpConnector
    ): WebClient {

        val oauth = ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository)

        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("authProvider")
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true)

        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("baseUrl")
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
            .filter(oauth)
            .build()
    }
}
```

And I'm using it here:

```
    fun callExternalService() {

        val retrieve = webClient.get()
            .uri("/uri")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
            .block()

        // ...
    }
```

My application.yml has the following structure

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          authProvider:
            token-uri: https://authentication-uri.com
        registration:
          authProvider:
            client-id: client-id
            client-secret: client-secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: any
```

This code is failing because my internal authentication service accepts only **password grant-type** and I can see the response for my auth URL returning a 400 code. Once I change `authorization-grant-type: authorization_code` to `authorization-grant-type: password`, spring ignores all the logic of authentication, it does not try to authenticate.

Does anyone know how to implement `authorization-grant-type: password`?

Comment: Based on the matrix of the GitHub repository of Spring Security, it should be able to work with the `password` grant type: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix

Comment: for now, try to debug the `PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` class which should handle your `password` flow and see whether it is invoked and maybe where the failure occurs